# Question regarding equality of two limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

If $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} [f(x,y)-a-b(x-x_0)-c(y-y_0)]=\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} [f(x,y)-A-B(x-x_0)-C(y-y_0)],$$ can one conclude that $a=A$, $b=B$, and $c=C$? Intuitively it seems to be true, but is it true? In this context $f$ is assumed to be differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$. How could one prove that it is true/false?

P.S. This is not my homework.

Comment: Intuitively it seems to be false because the delta terms vanish.

Answer (score 0):

taking the limit of the difference,

we will get

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}(a-A+(b-B)(x-x_0)+(c-C)(y-y_0)=a-A=0$ for all $b,B,c$ and $C$.

so what we can say is $a=A$.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, since $f$ is differentiable, in particular it is continuous so both limits evaluate to $f(x_0,y_0) - a$ and $f(x_0,y_0) - A$ respectively, regardless of the values $b$, $c$, $B$ and $C$. You can, though, conclude that $a = A$.

Answer (score 0):

If the two limits exist, then the difference of the limits is the limit of the difference and

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} [f(x,y)-a-b(x-x_0)-c(y-y_0)]-\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} [f(x,y)-A-B(x-x_0)-C(y-y_0)]=
\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} [A-a-(B-b)(x-x_0)-(C-c)(y-y_0)]=A-a=0.$$

All you can say is $A=a$, and differentiability is not required.

Comment: Crossed with @AbdallahHammam.